# Sumar input de una determinada columna dentro de una tabla, sumar a medida que escribe en el input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, datatables

Tengo una tabla a la cual necesito agregar en su *tfoot* un total por columnas, los valores que debe sumar son `input type=text` que están dentro de cada `td` de la tabla.

Es importante que a medida que escriba en los `input` se vaya reflejando el total en el *tfoot* de la columna que le corresponde.

[Adjunto link jsfiddle con lo que intento hacer](https://jsfiddle.net/fernandoaguayo/78sc0fmk/24/).

```html
<table id="table" name="table" class="table" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="">Auto</th>
      <th>Enero</th>
      <th>Febrero</th>
      <th>Marzo</th>
      <th>Abril</th>
      <th>Mayo</th>
      <th>Junio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="contenido-tabla">
    <tr>
      <td>Fiat</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="10"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="30"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="20"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="5"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="90"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="80"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Chevrolet</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="40"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="20"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="20"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="60"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="50"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="60"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mazda</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="5"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="90"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="80"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="60"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="60"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="15"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>Total:</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo hasta momento? De ser así, por favor inclúyelo en tu pregunta. Para hacer lo que quieres existen muchas maneras, una de ellas podría ser asignarle un id a cada `tr` para después buscar todos los inputs de sus `td`'s y poder hacer la suma y mostrarla en su respectiva columna. Para que sea "en tiempo" real, puedes asignar un event listener a cada input o utlizar la propiedad HTML `onchange` en su defecto.

Comment: Gracias por responder ricardo-dlc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo una propuesta usando `jQuery`.

Con esta opción no tienes que preocuparte por agregar más código en `js` si agregas más meses o mas autos *(columnas o filas)* de forma manual o dinámica en el `html`, ya que está pensado para recalcular los totales cada vez que se realice un cambio en cualquier campo.

Se agregó la clase **cantidad** a cada celda y la clase **total** a las celdas de la última fila para poder realizar los cálculos de manera adecuada. Adicionalmente, se cambió el tipo de `input` a `number` para evitar que te ingresen texto.

El código en `js` está comentado para facilitar la comprensión de lo que hace cada paso.

```js
//Ejemplo 1
//Se ejecuta si se cambia la cantidad con los números del teclado
$("#table .cantidad").keyup(function() {
    let total = 0;
    //Captura la posición de la columna en la que se está haciendo el cambio
    let index = $(this).parents('tr').find('.cantidad').index(this);
    //Captura el valor que hay en cada celda
    $("table tbody tr").each(function(i, row) {
      let cantidad = $(row).find('td').eq(index + 1).find('.cantidad').val();
      //Si el valor es numérico se hace la suma para evitar que muestre NaN en el total cuando las cantidades estén vacías
      if ($.isNumeric(parseFloat(cantidad))) {
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(cantidad)
      }
    });
    //Se asigna la suma al total correspondiente
    $('.total').eq(index).html(total);
});


//Ejemplo 2
//Se ejecuta si se cambia la cantidad con los controles del campo de tipo number
$("#table .cantidad").change(function() {
    let total = 0;
    let index = $(this).parents('tr').find('.cantidad').index(this);
    $("table tbody tr").each(function(i, row) {
      let cantidad = $(row).find('td').eq(index + 1).find('.cantidad').val();
      if ($.isNumeric(parseFloat(cantidad))) {
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(cantidad)
      }
    });
    $('.total').eq(index).html(total);
});
```

```css
.cantidad{
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" name="table" class="table" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Auto</th>
      <th>Enero</th>
      <th>Febrero</th>
      <th>Marzo</th>
      <th>Abril</th>
      <th>Mayo</th>
      <th>Junio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="contenido-tabla">
    <tr>
      <td>Fiat</td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Chevrolet</td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mazda</td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="" class="cantidad"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola @DjCrazy, se entiende perfecto, muchas gracias por la explicación, el tiempo y el codigo.!!

Answer (score 2):

Hola @Fernando Aguayo te muestro un código que te puede resultar útil:

```js
    function sumar(e){
        let element= document.querySelectorAll(e);
        let total= 0;
        element.forEach(function(e){
            total += parseInt(e.value);
        })
        //console.log(total);
        return total;

    }

    function resultado(e,g){
            let resultado= document.getElementById(g);
            resultado.innerHTML= sumar(e)
    }

    function evento(e,g){
    const clase= e;
    const id_resultado= g;

    
    resultado(clase,id_resultado);

    let element= document.querySelectorAll(e);
    element.forEach(function(e){
           
            e.addEventListener("keyup",function(){
                 if(e.value === ""){
                    e.value= 0;
                     }else{
                             e.value= parseInt(e.value);
                         }
                    resultado(clase,id_resultado);
                })
        })
    }

    evento('.enero','enero');
    evento('.febrero','febrero');
    evento('.marzo','marzo');
    evento('.abril','abril');
    evento('.mayo','mayo');
    evento('.junio','junio');
```

```html
<table id="table" name="table" class="table" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="">Auto</th>
      <th>Enero</th>
      <th>Febrero</th>
      <th>Marzo</th>
      <th>Abril</th>
      <th>Mayo</th>
      <th>Junio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="contenido-tabla">
    <tr>
      <td>Fiat</td>
      <td><input class="enero" type="text" value="10"></td>
      <td><input class="febrero" type="text" value="30"></td>
      <td><input class="marzo" type="text" value="20"></td>
      <td><input class="abril" type="text" value="5"></td>
      <td><input class="mayo" type="text" value="90"></td>
      <td><input class="junio" type="text" value="80"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Chevrolet</td>
      <td><input class="enero" type="text" value="40"></td>
      <td><input class="febrero" type="text" value="20"></td>
      <td><input class="marzo" type="text" value="20"></td>
      <td><input class="abril" type="text" value="60"></td>
      <td><input class="mayo" type="text" value="50"></td>
      <td><input class="junio" type="text" value="60"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mazda</td>
      <td><input class="enero" type="text" value="5"></td>
      <td><input class="febrero" type="text" value="90"></td>
      <td><input class="marzo" type="text" value="80"></td>
      <td><input class="abril" type="text" value="60"></td>
      <td><input class="mayo" type="text" value="60"></td>
      <td><input class="junio" type="text" value="15"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td id="enero">Total:</td>
      <td id="febrero">Total:</td>
      <td id="marzo">Total:</td>
      <td id="abril">Total:</td>
      <td id="mayo">Total:</td>
      <td id="junio">Total:</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Funciona de la siguiente manera: los input los he **identificado por clase**, esto permitirá que puedas añadir mas campos sin afectar el funcionamiento. Lo segundo a mencionar es que donde aparecerán los resultados los he referenciado con un **id**. Eso serian los ajustes que hice en tu HTML.

El JavaScript funciona de la siguiente manera: La función `evento` acepta dos parámetros: Primero la clase del input que identifica la columna y el segundo parámetro es el Id del elemento donde aparecerá el resultado. Esta función asignara el evento `keyup` a todos los inputs, para que cuando se escriba en ellos se realice la suma.

Además, el trabajo de la función `evento` esta repartido en dos funciones mas `sumar()` y `resultado()`. La función `resultado` llama a la función `sumar` que devuelve el total de una columna, `resultado()` pinta el valor de la operación en el elemento asignado en el id declarado previamente. El trabajo de la función sumar es para recuperar los valores de una columna en forma de un array y sumar sus valores con la ayuda de un `forEach().`

Espero que te sea útil.

Comment: Hola @Usiel, me funciono bien, el unico detalle es que las columnas que suma son dinamicas entonces llamar a la funcion evento por cada mes me limita, pero no lo exprese en la pregunta fue mi error. Delimite haciendolo por los 12 meses y funciona perfecto, muchas gracias por el tiempo, explicación y el codigo !!!!